# Shopping cart for guest user in stateless way

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-core, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am developing shopping website for my business myself!
I am using asp.net core web api for the backend of my project and i also use jwt for my authentication scheme!
I want that a guest user can add item to the shopping cart and when i search best approaches all of them were using session and cookie!
The main problem is that this is an web app and has android and ios and website application which are requesting to my web api!
And i can not use cookie  in the mobile!
Can anybody suggest me how to implement shopping cart for guest user without using session and cookie?

Comment: You need to generate a unique key for every guest user and then use memory or database, etc to store shopping items.

Comment: you can store all data on mobile for example use a SqlLite and for web users store data on localStorage